# Converting list of of string to list of lists of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like this:

```
['00000001000000000000000000000000', '11101000000000000000000000000000', '00011000000000000000000000000000', '11001000000000000000000000000000', '00101000000000000000000000000000', '10101000000000000000000000000000']
```

I want to group it in the chunks of equal lengths:

```
[['00000001000000000000000000000000', '11101000000000000000000000000000', '00011000000000000000000000000000'], ['11001000000000000000000000000000', '00101000000000000000000000000000', '10101000000000000000000000000000']]
```

Can any one please help me out?

Comment: 1. Which language? 2. What have you tried? 3. What is the logic of the conversion? Group into threes or something else?

Comment: In python language. It is not grouping into threes. it may be any n number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the length of the list is perfectly divisible by arbitrary number N, here is a basic script:

```
import copy
L = ['000','111','222','333','444','555','666','777','888']
new_L = []

chunk = []
for i, list_item in enumerate(L):
    chunk.append(list_item)
    if (i+1) % N == 0:
        new_L.append(copy.deepcopy(chunk))
        chunk=[]
```